# nginx, exclude single file from location

Tags: nginx

How can I exclude a single file from a location? The following block takes care of PHP processing globally:

```
location ~ \.php$  {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 150;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

What I want to do here is to exclude one single file called piwik.php as it should receive special treatment in a separate location. So My goal is to make it look a bit like this

```
location ~ \.php$ && NOT /stats/piwik.php  {
    ...
}
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5):

You're going to kick yourself when you see the answer.

> What I want to do here is to exclude one single file called piwik.php as it should receive special treatment in a separate location.

Ok, you should set that path as a separate location before your default one. e.g.

```
location ~ ^/stats/piwik.php$ {
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 150;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ \.php$  {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 150;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

As those are both regular expression location blocks, the one listed first in the Nginx conf that matches will have priority.

However, you presumably should be protected the whole of that directory. That can be done even more easily by using a matching prefix location rule:

```
location ^~ /stats/ {
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 150;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ \.php$  {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 150;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Because matching prefix have a higher priority that regex matches, it shouldn't matter which order they are in your nginx conf. A good explanation of the [priority for matches is here](http://fisharebest.stonystratford.org/116/understanding-nginx-location-rules/)

Comment: Fix the code block `location ~ ^/stats/piwik.php$ { allow 127.0.0.1; deny all;`, i couldn't edit it cause i need at least 6 characters to edit :D